# Unable to connect to mirrors.kernel.org Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to do an apt-get update;apt-get upgrade to update some of the packages that require updating, everytime I try to apt-get update I am getting unable to connect to mirrors.kernel.org. I am guessing this is related to the recent kernel.org compromise but can anyone lend a hand as to how to update my sources.list with something that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kernel.org was hacked recently. The server is currently down for maintenance. Wait some days or look for mirrors on the Net. I would prefer to wait.